# bat file variables return nul

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am writing a bat file and the variable return nul:

```
@echo Off
set DEF_APACHE_NAME = Apache
echo DEF_APACHE_NAME: %DEF_APACHE_NAME%
```

Returns:

```
DEF_APACHE_NAME:
```

Anyone know why the "Apache" is not in string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the spaces around the `=` sign.